# Polygon to polyline conversion

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, convert

I've got a polygon of agriculture field. I want to fill this polygon area with polylines in equal spaces between them (it supposed to represent the tree lines). those lines are not only for symbolic use, its should be for analysis.

Is there any way to convert this polygon into polyline like I described? I have tried to use the "polygons to line" tool but it gives me only the scope of the polygon and not the fill.

Comment: Is this just for display purposes or are you wanting to add attributes/do some analysis on the polylines?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In order to accomplish your stated goal, you'd need to construct lines of the desired separation and orientation, then clip them with your polygon. If you just want  a linear fill symbol, you should [edit] the question to specify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose a field like this (orthophoto + field limit shapefile):

[image]

Calculate distance between trees (I take minimum 10 trees prior to calculate mean):

[image]

Create a vector grid with tree spacing in `x` and a big space in `y` (in this case, you could use tree spacing in `y`):

[image]

Rotate lines (if needed):

[image]

The result should be something like this:

[image]

The final step is to clip geometries... I used intersect tool:

[image]

And the final result:

[image]